# Why does this JButton extension cause visual problems in the frame?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to create a JPanel that shows buttons forming a square of X size. I want to have the coordinates in a class that extends `JButton`, but when doing the extension some serious visual problems appear in the frame. If I remove it and use a normal `JButton` it doesn't happen.

I didn't find another public question with a similar problem. Can someone help me please?

**Edit:** Thanks to the comments noticed that I accidentally overridden the 'getX' and 'getY' methods of the Container superclass with my extension, that caused problems when it came to locating the JButtons and displaying them in the frame. Thanks.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainclass extends JFrame{
    private int size= 10;
    
    private class Button extends JButton{
        private int x;
        private int y;
        
        public Button(int x, int y) {
            super();
            this.x= x;
            this.y= y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public mainclass(){
        GridLayout gl= new GridLayout(size,size);
        JPanel buttonsPane= new JPanel(gl);
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
             for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                Button temp= new Button(row,col);
                temp.setVisible(true);
                buttonsPane.add(temp);
                buttonsPane.revalidate();
                buttonsPane.repaint();
             }
         }
        
        buttonsPane.setVisible(true);
        
        getContentPane().add(buttonsPane);
        setSize(700,700);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Buscaminas");
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainclass mc = new mainclass();
        mc.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you overriding getX/Y? You don’t seem to understand the responsibilities of the layout manager

Comment: The layout manager is setting the “frame” (location/size) of the button via setBounds and/or setLocation, but your getX/Y are returning what ever you’ve previously set - they have no relation to the super properties